# MKMapView - Stroking a path

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext, mapkit

Im trying to stroke and fill a path for an overlay view for a MapView. Now the fill works, the stroke doesnt... Any ideas from looking at the code below?

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{    
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.4);

    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 8.0);

    CGPoint pt;
    pt = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0))];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y);

    pt = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-2, 3))];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y);

    pt = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-2, 5))];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y);

    pt = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-4, 4))];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made it work...

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale));
```